# Passing variable from ViewPager Activity to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to do this without using a bundle. The reason I am trying to avoid that is because the data is pulled from a database online and I don't want the fragments to not load while it's waiting to get the data. From what I can tell I can only do the bundle arguments if the data is ready to send before any of the fragments are created.

This would cause a problem because the data isn't pulled from the database until the ViewPager is created. I can successfully pass the variables, but like I said the data isn't there instantaneously. This ends up sending a zero value through the bundle variable.

Am I incorrect in assuming you can't still pass bundles after the fragment creation? Aside from Bundles, what would be the best way to send a variable from the ViewPager to the Fragment? Would storing the data in the cache be a good option?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a method within your fragment to be called from your activity once you have retrieved said data from database.  Then within your fragment method you can load it to where ever you need and however you need.

Only thing you have to be concerned about is the static context of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast your `Activity` to `Fragment.getActivity` then invoke a getter for your data.

Alternatively, you could use a `Loader` and implement [LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) in your `Fragment` to return the data from your database, but only initialize it once the data has been set.

I suppose you could also show some sort of loading `Fragment`, then replace it with the other after the data is set. You could use a `Bundle` in that case.

There are lots of ways to solve this. And yeah, the `Fragments` arguments can't be passed after creation, unless you call `Fragment.setArguments` before it's attached to the `Activity`.

**Source**

[Fragment.instantiate](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#L588)

[Fragment.setArguments](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#L689)

Comment: Could you expand more on using the getter with the getActivity() function?